# How do I write a vim function to output the result of a system command?

Tags: vim

What I have so far:

```
function! GetMarker()
    return system('echo $random `date` | md5sum | cut -d" " -f1')
endfunction
```

I would like to be able to do a `:getmarker` and have it insert the output of that system command at my cursor, with no new lines.

Also what is the difference between `function!` and `function`?

Edit: before any of you ask, I need the random string to mark sections in my code so I can find them again by referencing my notes in my todo wiki.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit1. Take two. Trying to absorb the feedback from Luc. Without temp file (`readfile()` turned out to be not available in VIM 6.x I have on some systems).

```
:function InsertCmd( cmd )
:       let l = system( a:cmd )
:       let l = substitute(l, '\n$', '', '')
:       exe "normal a".l
:       redraw!
:endfunction

:imap <silent> <F5> <C-O>:call InsertCmd( 'echo date \| md5sum \| cut -d" " -f1' )<CR>
:map <silent> <F5> :call InsertCmd( 'echo date \| md5sum \| cut -d" " -f1' )<CR>
```

`:put` can't be used because it works line-wise. I replaced `<Esc>...<Insert>` with the all better `<C-O>`. I left redraw in, as it helps for the cases of called command produces output to the stderr.

Or using `<C-R>=`:

```
:function InsertCmd( cmd )
:       let l = system( a:cmd )
:       let l = substitute(l, '\n$', '', '')
:       return l
:endfunction

:imap <silent> <F5> <C-R>=InsertCmd( 'echo date \| md5sum \| cut -d" " -f1' )<CR>
```

> Also what is the difference between `function!` and `function`?

Exclamation on the end of command most of the time means force to execute. (Looking in the `:help` is advised since different commands use `!` differently, but VIM tries to document all forms of the commands.) In the case of the `function` it tells VIM to override previous definition of the function. E.g. if you put the code above into the `func1.vim` file, first time `:source func1.vim` would work fine, but the second time it would fail with error that function InsertCmd is already defined.

---

I did once before try to implement [something similar here](http://vimrc-dissection.blogspot.com/2008/03/inserting-command-output-from-function.html). I'm not good at VIM programming, thus it looks lame and the suggestion from Luc should take precedence.

Here it goes anyway:

```
:function InsertCmd( cmd )
:       exe ':silent !'.a:cmd.' > /tmp/vim.insert.xxx 2>/dev/null'
:       let l = readfile( '/tmp/vim.insert.xxx', '', 1 )
:       exe "normal a".l[0]
:       redraw!
:endfunction

:imap <silent> <F5> <Esc>:call InsertCmd( 'hostname' )<CR><Insert>
:map <silent> <F5> :call InsertCmd( 'hostname' )<CR>
```

Despite being lame, it works though.

Comment: If there is one issue with your approach, it is related to the temporary file. Multiple users cannot use the same script. It's better to use tempname(). Otherwise, a few things may be enhanced: - no redraw, - return l[0], - and insert it with `<c-r>=` to avoid oddities with the cursor position.

Comment: @Luc: `<c-r>=` - very very cool. `tempname()` - good to know too. Thanks for the advises.

Comment: "Exclamation on the end of command means force to execute." That's not true. There are many counter-examples. See `:g`, `:delm`, `:put`, ...

Comment: @Luc Hermitte: in the `!` part wording is changed. hope now it is better.

Answer (score 5):

You can trim/chomp the last newline with `matchstr()`, `substitute`, `[:-2]`, etc

```
function s:GetMarker()
  let res = system('echo $random `date` | md5sum | cut -d" " -f1')
  " then either
  let res = matchstr(res, '.*\ze\n')
  " or
  let res = res[:-2]
  " or
  let res = substitute(res, '\n$', '', '')
  return res
endfunction
command! -nargs=0 GetMarker put=s:GetMarker()
```

Banging the function/command definition (with '!') will permit you to source the script where it is defined several times and thus to update the function/command you are maintaining without having to exit vim.

Comment: This still inserts the hash on a new line, is there a way to get it to insert at the cursor?

Comment: Yes. You will have to play with things like exe+normal. But commands are not the best construct for this kind of text manipulation.
-> `command! -nargs=0 GetMarker exe "normal \<c-r>=s:GetMarker()\<esc>"`

Answer (score 0):

I was running into similar problems with trying to map a hotkey to insert the current date and time. I solved the newline problem by just including a <backspace>, but this still inserted newlines when I was indented (backspace would kill the last character, but when I was indented I got newline+tab and only the tab would go away).

So I did this -- just turned smartindent off, insert the string, then turn it back on:

```
imap <F5> <esc>:set nosmartindent<CR>a<C-R>=system('echo $random `date` \| md5sum \| cut -d" " -  f1')<CR><Backspace><esc>:set smartindent<CR>a
```

...which works, but it gets un-indented if you're sitting on a new, auto-indented line. To get around that, insert a character to hold your place, *then* escape, turn off smartindent, get rid of the extra character, and do the rest:

```
imap <F5> x<esc>:set nosmartindent<CR>a<backspace><C-R>=system('echo $random `date` \| md5sum \|  cut -d" " -f1')<CR><Backspace><esc>:set smartindent<CR>a
```

This seems to work.