# vim: how to use variables in titlestring

Tags: vim

I want to set the `&titlestring` in my `.vimrc` to contain the short hostname.  When I have this, it works fine:

```
let &titlestring = $USER . "@" . hostname() . " | " . expand("%:~")
if &term == "screen"
  set t_ts=^[k
  set t_fs=^[\
endif
if &term == "screen" || &term =~ "xterm"
  set title
endif
```

But it prints the full hostname.  In order to get the short hostname, I tried this:

```
let hostname=system('hostname -s')
let &titlestring = hostname . " | " . expand("%:~")
if &term == "screen"
  set t_ts=^[k
  set t_fs=^[\
endif
if &term == "screen" || &term =~ "xterm"
  set title
endif
```

But then I get `| ~/.vimrc` `echo`ed to the input line and `Thanks for flying Vim` in the titlebar.  How do I get the short hostname in the titlebar?

Comment: @Ingo Karkat gave the right answer. Regarding your problem I suspect this is a typical trailing newline issue with `system(). [Chomp it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3208405/how-do-i-write-a-vim-function-to-output-the-result-of-a-system-command)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wouldn't launch an external command for that; the `system()` call in your `.vimrc` may explain the strange symptoms.

Why don't you extract the short hostname (first part, up to `.`) via `substitute()`?!

```
let &titlestring = $USER . "@" . substitute(hostname(), '\..*$', '', '') . " | " . expand("%:~")
```